# Nx cypress - adding custom plugin for visual testing

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-e2e, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I am trying to set up a one of visual testing plugin from cypress https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/#visual-testing but in nrwl nx monorepo.

I follow the guide from https://github.com/meinaart/cypress-plugin-snapshots but can't make it work.

Actual result is that toMatchImageSnapshot doesn't work ( I have `is not a function` error )

Does anybody faced same problem and know a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a fix was here in this issue github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1609